# Cross-Origin @font-face

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, fonts, cross-domain

I'm having trouble getting a font I installed with @font-face to work with a new static subdomain.

I've been following the steps to set up a cookie-less subdomain outlined by [IT Support Guides](https://www.itsupportguides.com/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain/).

When I add:

```
    define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.example.net");
    define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.example.net");
    define("WP_PLUGIN_URL", "http://static.example.net/plugins");
```

the **wp.config** file, and

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
        SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.net" env=IS_CORS
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.net"
</FilesMatch>
```

to the **.htaccess**, I get a cross-origin error for the font I have installed in my theme folder (the font isn't displayed).

I'm guessing I'm not quite doing something right with the .htaccess file, but I'm not sure what. I've seen in some people using "*" instead of the "example.net", but that doesn't appear to help either.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Here is the error I see in Chrome:
"Font from origin 'http://static.example.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.example.net' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://example.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This question will probably be better off on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you paste the error in the qiestion

Comment: Does the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response really have `www.` in it while the `Origin` value in the request does not—that is,  `http://www.example.net` vs `http://example.net`? If so, those aren’t the same origin. If the host part of the URL is different at all, then that makes the origin different. The request and response both either need to have `http://www.example.net` or they both need to have `http://example.net`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

It appears shideshowbarker may have been on the right track. I changed the wp.config to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
    SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.net" env=IS_CORS
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.net"
</FilesMatch>
```

and got it to work today. I tried this before, but because I'm using a CDN it must have been using a cached version of the wp.config, while pulling the new htaccess file. Since it didn't update the wp.config I kept getting the same error even after I changed the file.

Leaving the changes in the wp.config a few days might have been enough to allow the CDN to update the cache. Alternatively I could have just told the CDN to empty the cache.